# How to prove that the difference of squares of two natural numbers can't be a perfect square if their sum is a perfect square?

Tags: proof-verification, square-numbers, pythagorean-triples, infinite-descent

I came across the following problem and wrote up the following proof a few years ago - what do you think?

---

It is required to demonstrate the truth of Statement S1: "If $a^2 + b^2$ is a perfect square, then $a^2 - b^2$ can't be one.

Assume that S1 is false and that $a^2 - b^2$ is a perfect square. Then there exists $m < a$ such that $a^2 - b^2 = m^2$. This implies that $b^2 + m^2$ is a perfect square. Again, with S1 assumed false, the difference between $b^2$ and $m^2$ would be a perfect square $n^2$ smaller than at least one of them. We should be able to continue this process, getting smaller and smaller perfect squares $m^2$, $n^2$...ending at $3^2$, corresponding to $5^2 - 4^2 = 3^2$. However, $5^2 + 4^2 = 41$ is not a perfect square. Hence S1 must be true. QED?

PS: The above argument seems to be Fermat's method of infinite descent. I wonder if Fermat's method of infinite descent can be used to prove his last theorem. Incidentally, I think the following "proof" of Fermat's Last Theorem holds only for Pythagorean triples: http://script864.rssing.com/chan-14851556/latest.php#item23

Comment: The assumption that S1 is false just says there exist $a,b$ such that both $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ are squares; it doesn't say that for all $a,b$ such that one of $a^2+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2$ is a square, so is the other one.

Comment: Just FYI, if $b = 0$, then this is eminently possible.

Comment: I realize that the proof I had outlined (hopefully dubbed correctly as "Fermat's method of infinite descent") would hold only for the following statement:
"For all natural numbers a, b and c, if a^2 + b^2 is a perfect square, then a^2 - b^2 is not a perfect square."

Say:
A: a^2 + b^2 is a perfect square.
B: a^2 - b^2 is not a perfect square.
~B: a^2 - b^2 is a perfect square.

Now, S1: A => B or ~B => ~A
Then ~S1: A and ~B

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Proof by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent#Non-solvability_of_r2_+_s4_=_t4_and_its_permutations) has been used to prove $x^4+y^4=z^4$ has no positive integer solutions (a special case of Fermat's last theorem)